# How can i fix my drop down menu for IE9?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-9

i have this CSS built hover-over drop-down menu that I'd like to use on my site. It works fine for all browsers except IE9. here is my code and my sheet:

[Sheet and code](http://timdebruyn8.wix.com/ie9problemhelp#!home/mainPage)

does anyone know what seems to be wrong? I'm not that good or experienced with building sites etc....

Comment: Firstly: **Put your code on StackOverflow!** Secondly: What's wrong with IE? I've putted your code in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GP7RZ/); looks like everything is fine for Chrome & IE 9.

Comment: You need to organize your question and your code before posting on StackOverflow. Try to separate your code and puts it in http://jsfiddle.net/. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test this in ie9 (on an Mac currently), but maybe you could try changing from `visibility:hidden;` to `display:none;` and change `visibility:visible;` to `display: block;`